# convert list to string separated by ','in python 3.7

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.7

I have upgraded python from 2.7 to 3.7.

In 2.7, I do

```
",".join(my_list)
```

to convert from list to string, but in 3.7, I have a error:

> `{TypeError}sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

How can I do this?

I've tried adding

```
b','.join(mylist)
```

but it returns an error:

> `{TypeError}sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found`

example:

```
mylist = ['try' , 'to' , 'be' , 'string']

output = 'try,to,be,string'
```

Comment: Where is your list coming from? a file?

Comment: just do `','.join(mylist)` get rid of the `b`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that doesn't address the question.  They're already doing that.

Comment: The join isn't the problem I think, your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Try ",".join(list)

Comment: yes the problem was with my data 
one of my items in a list was encoded so it converts from string to binary
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply drop the `b`, you only need it if your list items are also binary strings.

```
mylist = ['try' , 'to' , 'be' , 'string']
print( ','.join(mylist) )
```

Output:

```
try,to,be,string
```

But you have to make sure not to mix str and binary-str items:

```
mylist = ['try' , b'to' , 'be' , 'string']
print( ','.join(mylist) )
```

Output:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Comment: print( ','.join([str(a) for a in mylist])) Should do the trick

Comment: @E.Serra it will prevent the exception, but it will print literal ``"b'to'"``, so the output would be ``try,b'to',be,string`` - IMHO it's better to clean the input than to silently prevent an exception and then wonder where the garbage output is coming from.

Comment: definitely, but OP is wondering why it crashes, don't think he is going anywhere near production soon :)

Comment: @E.Serra why not `print(','.join(a if isinstance(a, str) else a.decode() for a in mylist))`?

Answer (score 0):

so actually the old version works for me

```
','.join(mylist)
```

I think you have the problem that one of your strings is a byte object... between byte and string you can convert using .encode and .decode

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm in a similar situation as OP: using Python 3.7, I'm reading line by line a file that is opened in binary mode, so I obtain a list of binary strings.

In my case those lines are JSON objects (one per line): I need to put them in a JSON array and parse them. To do this I have to decode each line to a string:

```py
json_obj = json.loads(
    "[" + ",".join(map(lambda l: l.decode(), file.readlines())) + "]"
)
```

In this snippet, `file.readlines()` produces a list of `b''` (binary strings), and I'm using `map()` to call `.decode()` on each of them to turn it in a utf8 string, so that `join()` can do its job.

This approach can also work in case of mixed types in the list (strings and binary), but you would need to implement a custom `decode()`:

```py
def decode(arg):
    try:
        return arg.decode()
    except:
        pass
    return arg

json_obj = json.loads(
    "[" + ",".join(map(lambda l: decode(l), file.readlines())) + "]"
)
```